# Jenkins: how to get specific dependency version in pom.xml via readMavenPom or mvn help:evaluate?

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml, jenkins-groovy

Already read a ton of pages and howtos and learnt that `readMavenPom` returns a *Model* object.
It's quite easy to get root values, but how can I get a specific dependency version?

Using `mvn help:evaluate` doesn't help either: I don't know *what* to evaluate to get the info.

Can anyone give some advice?

Made a lot of tests but I actually totally ignore what should I evaluate.

Comment: Why do you need the version of pom file in Jenkins? Can you explain what the purpose of this is?

Comment: I have to build and deploy a workflow kjar for a jBPM server with a Jenkins pipeline; I can't edit the pom.xml and I'd prefer to use the kie-server-maven-plugin version that matches the version of the org.kie:kie-api dependency declared in the pom.xml file (which in turn matches the version of the jBPM server on which the sources have been developed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model object contains all the information related to dependencies as well:

```
pipeline{
    
    agent{label "master"}
    stages{
        stage('1'){
            steps{
                script{
                    def pom = """
                    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.passfailerror</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dependency.one</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact-name1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dependency.two</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact-name2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </project>
                    """
                    
                    writeFile file:"pom.xml", text:pom
                    def model = readMavenPom file:"pom.xml"
                    
                    echo model.getDependencies().findAll{it.artifactId == "artifact-name2"}.first().getVersion()
                    echo model.getDependencies().findAll{it.groupId == "com.dependency.one"}.first().getVersion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

You can easily find version of each dependency entry by artifactId, groupId or anything you want.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. And, trust me, not easy to guess at all for those who are unfamiliar with Java ;-).
Can you also tell what should I put between braces if I want to select both by groupId and artifactId (in theory I can have 2 dependencies with the same artifactIds but different groupIds, I'd feel more comfortable by specifying both).

Comment: You just need to filter things one after another: findAll == filtering:
`model.getDependencies().findAll{it.groupId == "com.dependency.one"}.findAll{it.artifactId == "artifact-name2"}.first().getVersion()`